# How to compile and run arduino code in Visual studio? (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to compile and upload the simple blink.ino for an Arduiono Uno in VisualStudio code.
In both cases I get an error in the terminal:

```
[192-168-0-8.local..recover()] WARN javax.jmdns.impl.JmDNSImpl - RECOVERING
[JmDNS(192-168-0-8.local.).State.Timer] WARN javax.jmdns.impl.tasks.state.DNSStateTask - Canceler(192-168-0-8.local.).run() exception 
java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted (sendto failed)
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at javax.jmdns.impl.JmDNSImpl.send(JmDNSImpl.java:1634)
    at javax.jmdns.impl.tasks.state.DNSStateTask.run(DNSStateTask.java:131)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install the PlatformIO (extension).